# force src on @font-face using SASS

Tags: css, sass

I have some custom fonts in my project and reference them by using @font-face.
But when the SASS is compiled the src gets all wrong, pointing to the original folder. I want it to point to the current folder where the CSS file is.

**SASS**:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: Default;
    src: url("Poppins-Medium.ttf");
}

@font-face {
    font-family: Regular;
    src: url("Poppips-Regular.ttf");
}

@font-face {
    font-family: SemiBold;
    src: url("Poppins-SemiBold.ttf");
}

@font-face {
    font-family: Bold;
    src: url("Poppins-Black.ttf");
}
```

**Compiled SASS**:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: Default;
  src: url("../../STYLE/Layout/Poppins-Medium.ttf"); }

@font-face {
  font-family: Regular;
  src: url("../../STYLE/Layout/Poppips-Regular.ttf"); }

@font-face {
  font-family: SemiBold;
  src: url("../../STYLE/Layout/Poppins-SemiBold.ttf"); }

@font-face {
  font-family: Bold;
  src: url("../../STYLE/Layout/Poppins-Black.ttf"); }
```

I want the source to be "Poppins-Black.ttf", since they are in the same folder.

Comment: Did you try adding `./` before the font file names?

Comment: @Arkellys yes, but still same result, relative to the build folder

Comment: What are you using to compile the sass?

Comment: @Arkellys the Web Compiler extension for Visual studio

Answer (score 0):

I ended up copying the font files to the build folder and reference them from there,